# MySql AND OR confusion in yaml file

Tags: mysql, sql, yaml

table name is "Student s"
where columns are s_id,tested_date,form and OtherIformation A to I. 
yaml files have conditions like :

```
/*OPT and s.tested_date <= :Date */
/*OPT and s.form in ( :formFilter ) */
/*OPT and s.OtherInformationA in (:otherInformationA) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationB in (:otherInformationB) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationC in (:otherInformationC) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationD in (:otherInformationD) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationE in (:otherInformationE) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationF in (:otherInformationF) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationH in (:otherInformationH) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationG in (:otherInformationG) */
/*OPT OR s.OtherInformationI in (:otherInformationI) */
```

Only Those parameters passed to yaml will get reflected in MySql native query. 
EX:
On Setting parameres Date,form and otherInformation A we get a native sql query as

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE s.tested_date <= :Date
AND s.form in ( :formFilter )
AND s.OtherInformationA in (:otherInformationA);
```

In above case i get only those students who has otherInformationA set 
I need 'or' Condition between OtherInformations such that i will get Student with otherInformationA or OtherInformationB Or OtherInformationC etc.

above Code fails when parameters passed to query are 'date','form' and 'otherInformationB'
In such case i get sql query as

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE s.tested_date <= :Date
AND s.form in ( :formFilter )
OR s.OtherInformationB in (:otherInformationB)
```

but i required native sql query as :

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE s.tested_date <= :Date
AND s.form in ( :formFilter )
AND (s.OtherInformationB in (:otherInformationB) Or s.OtherInformationC in (:otherInformationC) or s.OtherInformationD in (:otherInformationD));
```

how do i apply AND & OR condition in yaml file?

Comment: YAML is a markup language, how you use it is up to you. I suggest you provide **the relevant code** from whatever system is interpreting the markup.

Comment: @miken32 YAML stands for "YAML Ain’t Markup Language." YAML is a data serialization language, not a markup language. The rest of your comment is correct, though.

Comment: @Jordan Haha I've never used it before; I though it was "Yet Another Markup Language!"

Comment: I think it was that originally, but at some point someone pointed out to the author that it isn't a markup language at all so he changed it. ;)